# Having problems with hoisted functions and variables in Javascript, can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript

i've been trying to understand the concepts of hoisted functions and variables in javascript, and I found this excelent article http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/?WPACFallback=1&WPACRandom=1417555130400, but i have something that I still cannot solve or understand:

```
var myName = "Xavier";

function myName(){
    console.log("Mi nombre es Javier");
}
console.log(typeof myName); //this suppose to print "string" but insted I get "function".
```

According to what I read from the article Javascript does the following:

```
var myName;

function myName(){
    console.log("Mi nombre es Javier");
}
myName = "Xavier";
console.log(typeof myName); //prints "string"
```

According to the hoisted principle, both variable declarations an function declaration are hoisted to the top of their scope where they are defined.

To anyone who can help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: What javascript environment are you getting this result in?  I just tried it in the Firefox console and got the expected result in the first code example that you give ("string").  What browser is this? Or is it node.js?  Are you executing your code at the top level of the document, or in a function? Etc.  I'm very curious as to what's going on here!

Comment: what are you saying . :( Professor (X)Javier

Comment: If you type this line by line into the developer tools, it won't work. But you can reproduce it by putting it in a self-contained function: `function test(){ var x = "string"; function x(){}; console.info(typeof x); }`. This will print "string", because somehow the function declarations do happen "earlier", see @TigerScott's answer.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide more context information. All the answers so far are only stating what you already know and don't address your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the article you mentioned

> Both function declaration and variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the containing scope. And function declaration takes precedence over variable declarations (but not over variable assignment)

I tested the first block of code you mentioned in the question by running it in the firefox and the output I got was "string" as expected.

This code will give the output "function".

```
var foo;
function foo(){

}
console.log(typeof(foo));
```

PS: Please mention the environment you are using to run your code. Only then I would be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

When i read the article carefully, i get this - **Function Declaration Overrides Variable Declaration When Hoisted**
Both function declaration and variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the containing scope. And function declaration takes precedence over variable declarations (**but not over variable assignment**).
Does this help?

Comment: That does seem to be happening. Here is a self-contained test function, that should print "string" regardless of environment): `function test(){ var x = "string"; function x(){}; console.info(typeof x); }`

Comment: *"...but not over variable assignment"* Exactly. So how do you explain that the OP gets sees `//this suppose to print "string" but insted I get "function".`? You didn't actually answer the question at all, you just repeated what the OP already expected.

Comment: @FelixKling: I think OP used an interactive prompt and pasted line-by-line. There hoisting cannot happen. (you start running code before even entering the next line)

Comment: @Thilo: Probably. But none of the answers is addressing this. They are all not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It does as the article states?
http://jsfiddle.net/txhu587b/

```
var myName = "Xavier";

function myName(){
    console.log("Mi nombre es Javier");
}
console.log(typeof myName); //prints string
```

Comment: Yes, but you cannot reproduce it in the interactive console, because if you run this code line by line, there is no way that hoisting can happen.

Comment: It does work in the "non-interactive" console: Just paste all five lines together into the console prompt.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations.

```
var x = 5; // Initialize x
var y;     // Declare y
```

Comment: That OP already knows that. You don't seem to address the question at all.

Answer (score -1):

The code you post

```
var myName = "Xavier";

function myName() {
    console.log("Mi nombre es Javier");
}
console.log(typeof myName); //string
```

works exactly as you expected beacause typeof myName indeed is string. Please see the 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/b3c8k05t/)